# find similar documents before add

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, django-haystack, morelikethis

1. User fill multi-field form (document) with date, time, title and description.
2. Check, if similar documents are stored in Solr before document saved
3. User can choose, save this document or not.

How to implement in Solr *"find similar documents"*?

in Lucene: `FuzzyLikeThisQuery`, `MoreLikeThis`?

but in Solr?

P.S. I use django-hastack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solr also has a [MoreLikeThis](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis) component.